# Implement long-press FAB in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

[image]

Is it possible to implement a long-press for the fab that shows small buttons with labels on top of the fab without additional components?

If not how to implement it with additional components but the same visual result?

My current FAB looks like this:
https://codeberg.org/pabloscloud/Overload/src/commit/eae4132fd66d58d9ee52fe51ed18eb5bc2cd9f53/app/src/main/java/cloud/pablos/overload/ui/tabs/home/HomeTabFab.kt

```
FloatingActionButton(
        onClick = {
            /* onClick - event */
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp),
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.PlayArrow
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.edit),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),

            )
            TextView(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.start),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 0.dp, 8.dp, 0.dp),
            )
        }
    }
```

I tried using other components instead of a FAB but couldn't get it to act and look the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build this in 3 ways as i can think of probably there are other ways too.

You can  use `InteractionSource` to determine how long fab is pressed with `collectLatest` because need to trigger click on fast clicks and cancel previous action.

Second option is to copy-paste source code and use it with `Surface` that doesn't have onClick param and add `Modifer.combinedClickable`.

Third option is to create a `Modifier.pointerInput(){}` with `PointerEventPass.Initial` to get long click event before FloatingActionButton or Button.

I will post first option because this one is easier than copy-paste and modify solution.

You can also apply this solution to `Button` since it also takes `InteractionSource` as param.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    val viewConfiguration = LocalViewConfiguration.current


    LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
        var isLongClick = false

        interactionSource.interactions.collectLatest { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    isLongClick = false
                    delay(viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis)
                    isLongClick = true
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                    if (isLongClick.not()){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                }
                is PressInteraction.Cancel -> {
                    isLongClick = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    FloatingActionButton(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onClick = {},
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp),
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.PlayArrow,
                        contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),

                )
            Text(
                text = "Start",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 0.dp, 8.dp, 0.dp),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a good solution and I appreciate your time for helping me out here! I'll try it asap